# IIS 7.5 Custom error pages not working for file with extension

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, custom-error-pages

I am facing a starnge issue with one of my server, I've setup the custom error pages however error pages are not showing up when I have file extension in URL for example it does not work for somedomain.com/abcd.aspx or somedomain.com/abcd.aspx, it just show me blank page.

It is working if I dont have file extension in my URL for example http://somedomain.com/abcd works fine.

Following is the configuration setting in web.config file

```
<httpErrors  errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" existingResponse="Replace">
       <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error400.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error400.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error400.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error400.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error400.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error400.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/Error500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Any help or pointers will be great.

Regards,
Sameer

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've already solved this by now, but for others searching for the answer, I ran into this same issue today and was able to solve it by adding a customError handler in addition to the httpErrors.

Change:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

to:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
        <error redirect="/Errors/404" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
```